# How to change color of menukeys?

Tags: color, menukeys

I cannot understand how to change the colors of the text in the menus typeset using `menukeys`.  A minimal example (taken from the `menukeys` manual) follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma} \\
\directory{One / Two / Three} \\
\keys{\cmd + \shift + 4} \\[4ex]
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus}
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma} \\[4ex]
\changemenucolor{menu}{txt}{named}{red}
\changemenucolor{roundedmenus}{txt}{named}{red}
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma}
\end{document}
```

(the second `\changemenucolor` has been added since the first one didn't work; but the `\renewmenumacro` works like expected).  Any hint?

Comment: you should take a look at pages 9 and 10 of the `menukeys` documentation ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/menukeys/menukeys.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Yes, I have read the manual; my statement (\changemenucolor) is described at page 11.  In pages 9/10 I don't see anything relevant...

Comment: You are using default `gray` style, so you should use something like `\changemenucolor{gray}{txt}{named}{red}`

Comment: That indeed solved my problem.  Well, just a couple examples would have fit well in the manual...  probably that was all my fault, since english is my 3rd language only :(  And many many thanks to karlkoeller for the quick and exhaustive reply.

Comment: @Maurizio Don't worry, I'm Italian too, and I know what you mean...

Comment: I know that the manual must be improved but English is not my native language too ;-) I'm planning a new implementation of `menukeys` including a better manual but I don't find some time for that project …

Comment: @Maurizio I've turned the comment into an answer. Remember that, if you want, you can accept answers by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).

Answer (score 12):

Indeed the `menukeys` manual could contain a few more examples, but I'm sure that Tobi will do something for it (sooner or later).

Anyway, when you issue the command `\changemenucolor` you have to refer to a  "color theme" as a first argument (see Section 4.3 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/menukeys/menukeys.pdf):

```
\changemenucolor{<theme name>}{<element>}{<model>}{<color definition>}
```

There are two predefined color themes, `gray` and `blacknwhite`. You can even create new ones through the command `\newmenucolortheme`.

Anyway, unless you change it with `\changemenucolortheme`, the one used by default is `gray`, so the command you have to issue is

```
\changemenucolor{gray}{txt}{named}{red}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma} \\
\directory{One / Two / Three} \\
\keys{\cmd + \shift + 4} \\[4ex]
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus}
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma} \\[4ex]
\changemenucolor{gray}{txt}{named}{red}
\menu{Alfa > Beta > Gamma}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]